# intellij mongo error though not being used

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

I'm having an annoying error. I have just installed IntelliJ and opened a simple "hello world" jsp project. There is nothing about Mongo. But when I run war file I have this error:

```
WARN 24408 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.f actory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory met hod failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.Illeg alAccessError: tried to access method org.bson.types.ObjectId.<init>(III)V from class com.mongodb.Bytes 2019-03-18 00:32:45.264  INFO 24408 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat] 2019-03-18 00:32:45.298  INFO 24408 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2019-03-18 00:32:45.314 ERROR 24408 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication           : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean in stantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested e xception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.bson.types.ObjectId.<init>(III)V from class com.mongodb.Bytes
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEA SE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at pl.dmcs.rkotas.SpringBootJspApplication.main(SpringBootJspApplication.java:10) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [rkotas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [rkotas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [rkotas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:58) [rkotas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.bson.types.ObjectId.<init>(III)V from class com.mongodb.Bytes
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        ... 26 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.bson.types.ObjectId.<init>(III)V from class com.mongodb.Bytes
        at com.mongodb.Bytes.<clinit>(Bytes.java:226) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.Mongo.<clinit>(Mongo.java:76) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.2.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoClientFactory.createMongoClient(MongoClientFactory.java:111) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoClientFactory.createNetworkMongoClient(MongoClientFactory.java:107) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoClientFactory.createMongoClient(MongoClientFactory.java:67) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration.mongo(MongoAutoConfiguration.java:70) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$20af1816.CGLIB$mongo$1(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$20af1816$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1971336f.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.ja r!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$20af1816.mongo(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Can you please, please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more info, like your pom.xml. 
I would guess that there is a transitive dependency on mongo, try to add:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=MongoAutoConfiguration.class)
```

to your application class, according to this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2372) it may help.